# Google maps data type throws Type Error: can't convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, umbraco, webresource.axd

In all our Umbraco websites Google maps data type is not working anymore. This worked perfect till yesterday but today there is only the input-field and the location-field and not the Google maps...

Firebug reports the following error

Error: TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
Source File: http://mydomain.com/WebResource.axd?d=tKK1ZgJBCMotVXJtV8pR9xzMqTmklCMezxGDl1po1iuUqd9OAFswOEzHFzCaf_jVz-AUweHtY9QXIBqtRjeITKZJW8DsgNEfWr5d43rOLcGkPLOTDqcjla1Kf5Atxrk4V0fVru8i1i6pj_kgbZvebWAyHrkbCDipPWDziYWT-lCHW-WaHOcz5hS1DefZvkJSICxqjpdChghoCUZhju3cHg2&t=634759042640000000&cdv=1
Line: 212

Its in the line

```
context._maps[id] = new UmbracoGoogleMap.map(id, this);
```

in the following function

```
guiMap: function () {
    var context = this;
    this._apiLoaded = true;
    jQuery('div.gmapContainer').each(function () {
        var id = jQuery('div.map', this).attr('id');
        context._maps[id] = new UmbracoGoogleMap.map(id, this);
        context._maps[id].render();
    });
},
```

There is a lot of other people also reporting the same issue but couldn't find a solution yet!
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/google-maps-datatype/bug-reports/33390-No-map-in-Backend

Comment: One of references is undefined but the code tries to access it. My guess is that it is `context,_maps`. Another guess is that the `id` is undefied (the line above doesn't return the id) and the constructor throws an exception because for example it tries to get the div of given id and access its properties. Anyway, you just need some logging.

Comment: For me, the larger question is what occurred to make the JavaScript break across all installs? Since this issue was reported yesterday (on mass), were there any changes/updates to the Google Maps API that could have this impact?

Comment: @leekelleher it is perplexing - I can't find any google announcements on a breaking change but it seems the most likely reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was to do with the context.  It was being set to the window rather than the UmbracoGoogleMapMapDataType as "this" pointing to the wrong place.  So I tried:

```
var context = UmbracoGoogleMapMapDataType;
this._apiLoaded = true;
jQuery('div.gmapContainer').each(function () {
    var id = jQuery('div.map', this).attr('id');
    context._maps[id] = new UmbracoGoogleMap.map(id, this);
    context._maps[id].render();
});
```

And that now seems to work as a temporary patch.  If you want you can download the dll from https://www.dropbox.com/s/3aj91cuzxn3rcbu/Our.Umbraco.GoogleMaps.zip

Comment: +1 Great work, I can change \umbraco\editcontent.aspx and poke in the javascript at the bottom and it fixes the map.  But how would I reference the dll in your dropbox download to perform the same fix - I'm a bit confused?

Comment: You just unzip the dll and place it in your bin.

Comment: FYI, an updated version of the Google Maps DataType is now available for [download](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/google-maps-datatype).

Answer (score 1):

We did some digging in to why the error came about and apparently it's due to an update of the [Google Maps Javascript API](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog). We found that the permanent fix was to request a specific version of the API, by adding a `v: "3.8"` to the ajax request:

```
UmbracoGoogleMap.loadMapsApi = function (cb) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "script",
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js',
        data: {
            v: "3.8",
            sensor: false,
            callback: cb
    },
    error: function () { alert('Could not load Google Maps API'); }
});
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning), if no version is specified, then Google returns the latest nightly version. In fact, they specifically state that:

> Production applications should always specify a minor version (eg. 3.7, 3.8, etc.).

As we can see the latest version of 3.9 has broken compatibility with the Google Maps data type and thus the error.

**Update:** Version 2.0.5 of the [Google Maps DataType](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/google-maps-datatype) is now available and contains the above fix. Thanks to Lee Kelleher!

Comment: Thank you Douglas, this makes much more sense to me! #h5yr